# Prove that an open interval $(a,b)$ considered as a subspace of a real line is homeomorphic to the real line.

Tags: general-topology

I understand that in $(\Bbb R ,d)$, any open interval $(a,b)$ is topologically equivalent to $\Bbb R$. But here the topology is unspecific, so I have no idea how to proceed.

Could anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: $(a,b)$ should have the subspace topology. Otherwise, we can equip it with, say, the discrete topology and of course it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @QuangHoang But can the topology of the real line be unspecific? In that case I'm unable to associate it with the metric space $(\Bbb R, d)$

Comment: When you say *real line*, it means the usual metric topology.

Comment: I think that the standard topology on ${\mathbb R}$ is assumed, because otherwise it is easy to give counterexamples: Adopt the usual topology on $[a,b]$, and declare all singletons $\{x\}$ with $x<a$ or $x>b$ as open.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!!